# getting -[NSNull countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

Im trying to filter through an array and get rid of all the duplicate strings.

```
    NSMutableArray *initialWomensCategoryArray = [NSMutableArray new];

    for(NSArray *womensCategoryInnner in [objects valueForKey:@"womensCategory"])
    {
        for(id object in womensCategoryInnner)
        {

            [initialWomensCategoryArray addObject:object];

            womensDataArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
            for (id obj in initialWomensCategoryArray)
            {
                if (![womensDataArray containsObject:obj])
                {
                    [womensDataArray addObject: obj];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean with `getting -[NSNull countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]`? *Getting*??

Answer (score 0):

Above Error want to say **"You have getting NULL value"** when you have add Object into array. So you have two possibility for this error

1) `[initialWomensCategoryArray addObject:object]`

2) `[womensDataArray addObject: obj]`

I think you have to check for the first one(`[initialWomensCategoryArray addObject:object]`)

Comment: What should i look for?

Comment: my bad, found out that the database i was looking at, the array was empty.

Comment: Debug your code using break point and print value for each for loop before the add value(initialWomensCategoryArray,womensDataArray,obj,object)